# React + Vite: Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite

I am creating a Design System project using React + Vite. This project will be a GIT submodule used in other projects.

When importing the submodule into the other project and using the created components, the application returns the following error:

```
ERROR in ./packages/MightZord-DS/src/components/Switch/index.tsx 9:0

Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (9:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { FieldRow } from "../Field/styles";
| 
> interface SwitchFieldProps {
|     id: string;
|     label: string;
```

**MightZord-DS Project files:**

**File:** src/components/Switch/index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { SwitchRoot, SwitchThumb, LabelSwitch } from "./styles";
import { FieldRow } from "../Field/styles";

interface SwitchFieldProps {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    defaultValue?: boolean;
    updateValueField?: (value: boolean) => void;
}
const Switch = ({ id, label, defaultValue, updateValueField }: SwitchFieldProps) => {

    return (
        <FieldRow style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <LabelSwitch htmlFor={id}>
                {label}
            </LabelSwitch>
            <SwitchRoot
                className="SwitchRoot"
                id={id}
                checked={defaultValue}
                onCheckedChange={updateValueField}
            >
                <SwitchThumb className="SwitchThumb" />
            </SwitchRoot>
        </FieldRow>
    )
}

export default Switch
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@magazord/mightzord-ds",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.2",
    "polished": "^4.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

**vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

These components are exported in the index.ts file located at the root of the project.

**index.ts**

```
import Switch from './src/components/Switch'

export { Switch };
```

In the other project, I use the submodule strategy and import the component that I exported from the MightZord-DS project.

I tried to do everything they said in the other questions, but without success.

[Parsing error: The keyword 'interface' is reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70174124/parsing-error-the-keyword-interface-is-reserved)

[Webpack doesn't bundle TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279409/webpack-doesnt-bundle-typescript)

[The keyword 'interface' is reserved when using lerna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843637/the-keyword-interface-is-reserved-when-using-lerna)

[Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (5:0) File was processed with these loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71822618/module-parse-failed-the-keyword-interface-is-reserved-50-file-was-processe)

[Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved using turbo repo Next.js 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344485/module-parse-failed-the-keyword-interface-is-reserved-using-turbo-repo-next-j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It happened because I created the Design System project using Vite and the other application used Create React APP.

I changed the other projects to use Vite and it worked perfectly